# Python: Any optimized way to check that 2 lists increase together?

Tags: python, sequence

Let's assume we have 2 lists `a = [1,2,4,3,5]` and `b = [103,122,800,500,1000]`

is there an optimized way that I can check that they are "increasing together"?

My current solution, employs a loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(a)):
   if (a[i-1] < a[i] and b[i-1] > b[i]) or (a[i-1] > a[i] and b[i-1] < b[i]):
       print('wrong')
```

Is there a better way?

Notes:

- The solution does not need to be list specific (really any data structure would work)
- The two iterables do not need to increase by the same number of units, just have to increase together.

Comment: By optimize you want faster than current O(N)?

Comment: What do you mean with "increasing together"? That the elements in both lists are sorted in increasing order? Or that element[i] in one list is bigger then element[i] in the other list for all possible indices? Something else?

Comment: well there is the loop, and then there is the comparison operation itself. So really both. Looking whether I am oblivious to CS approach that has handled this more elegantly.

Comment: You might get some improvement in performance by phrasing this in terms of numpy ndarrays.

Comment: @quant what I mean is that regardless of initial sort of item that if element a[i] is larger than a[i-1] then the same is true for items at same indices in list b.

Comment: BTW, what behaviour do you expect if one of the lists changes (in either direction) while the other stays the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really get any faster than O(n), but you could make your code a bit shorter and maybe more readable by using `numpy.diff` and comparing the `sign` of the diffs of `a` and `b`:

```
>>> from numpy import diff, sign
>>> a, b = [1,2,4,3,5], [103,122,800,500,1000]
>>> sign(diff(a))
array([ 1,  1, -1,  1])
>>> all(sign(diff(a)) == sign(diff(b)))
True
>>> a, b = [1,2,4,3,5], [103,122,800,500,100]
>>> all(sign(diff(a)) == sign(diff(b)))
False
```

The downside of this solution is that it does not use lazy-evaluation, i.e. it calculates and compares the entire `sign(diff(...))` array even if the "increasingness" of `a` and `b` differs in the very first position. If the list is very long, you should consider using another approach.

Comment: I find this the most elegant, and it avoid an explicit loop. Thanks. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Your approach is actually fastest when one compares two large lists which increase together.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of O(order notation), you can't get better than linear, assuming lists don't have some order. But, you can use some python compiler like cython, numba to speed up your code. Your code using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def vary_together(a, b):
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
       if (a[i-1] < a[i] and b[i-1] > b[i]) or (a[i-1] > a[i] and b[i-1] < b[i]):
           return False
    return True
```

You have to use large lists to see the performance benefit. For example, if:

```
a = np.array([randint(0,100) for i in range(10000000)])
```

Then,

```
vary_together(a, a)  # a as both arguments so as to make it complete the loop
```

Has has the performance comparison to your solution as :

> Your solution: 8.09s
>   vary_together: 0.2 (on second run to discount for compile time).

If you need to run the code again and again in the script, do `cache=True` in the `nb.njit` decorator.

Comment: Good answer. But numba can look exotic for beginners. Add vary_together (a,ma) with ma=-a to enforce the lazy aspect. and compare with and without numba (4 cases)

Answer (score 2):

We can use the lazy evaluation provided by python iterators, meaning we don't need to continue traversing both lists ( structures ) once they don't have the same variation sign

```
def compare_variation( a, b ):
    a_variations = ( a[ i - 1 ] < a[ i ] for i in range( 1, len( a ) ) )
    b_variations = ( b[ i - 1 ] < b[ i ] for i in range( 1, len( b ) ) )
    return all( x == y for x, y in zip( a_variations, b_variations  ) )
```

Comment: If you still calculate the `diff` and `sign` for the entire lists `a` and `b`, lazy-evaluating whether they are equal does not lower the number of operations significantly, even if they differ in the very first comparison.

Comment: @tobias_k valid point i have updated my code accordingly, thanks a lot

Comment: You can just write `a[i-1] < a[i]` instead of `True if a[ i - 1 ] < a[ i ] else False`. Also, I'd suggest switching to Python 3, i.e. just use `range` and `zip`, which now return iterators instead of lists.

Comment: @tobias_k I have changed my code following your recommendations, thanks a loot

Comment: @tobias_k totally forgot about the xrange, thanks a lot, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with list comprehension:

```
c = [(a[x + 1] - a[x]) * (b[x + 1] - b[x]) for x in range(len(a) - 1)]
if any([x < 0 for x in c]):
    print('Wrong')
```

Comparing all the previous approaches (except for the numba one), tobias_k's answer looks like most efficient when dealing with large enough lists (at list 40 elements roughly).